# Is it okay to use different data preparation procedures for different models?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, model, data-preprocessing

I'm currently learning some basics of building models, and I was wondering whether it's okay to use different data preparation procedures for different models. Specifically, I was considering an example of using linear regression vs ridge regression and whether any features need to be removed. I read that ridge regression can deal with some multicollinearity since it reduces model complexity, so we don't necessarily need to perform feature selection before ridge regression. However, feature selection in linear regression is much more important. Would it be okay to do feature selection just in the linear regression?

My intuition is that this would be fine as this data preparation procedure can be thought of as part of the model - but I was wondering if there could be any issues with comparing models.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selecting (or constructing) variables is very much dependent on the model, e.g. if trying to model a quadratic relationship with a linear model you need to include an additional variable to capture this, while a random forest (example) model would not need such a variable since it can learn this relationship on its own (although it doesn't necessarily hurt to include it). Another case is the one you mention, ridge can deal with multicollinearity on its own (although you might not like how it chose to handle it), while linear regression cannot, so you should probably do something about it.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if, for your specific example, this counts as "data preparation" at all. While it's true that collinearity is a feature only of the independent variables, the usual procedure for diagnosing it involves doing collinearity diagnostics on a model, so you have to run a model to tell if you need to fix collinearity.

I think of "data preparation" as stuff that you do *before* running any models. There could be cases where you have to do some preparation for some models but not others. For instance, you may know, *a priori* that you want to change count data into yes/no data for some variable for one model but not others. This could happen if you have hypotheses about both presence/absence and count.  For example, if you have data on how many cars a family owns, you might have a hypothesis about whether they own a car at all and another about how many cars they own.